# Highchart : "Unfinished graph"

Tags: javascript, highcharts, graphics

We are today trying to use highchart instead of JQplot and we have pain to make an "unfinished" graph looks like this picture (Screened at 10:35):

### [image: Expected graph]

Can we make this kind of graph with highchart ? (With an "empty" part)

Thanks for help !

Comment: Define max for the axis http://jsfiddle.net/kqpvve9w/

Comment: Thanks a lot ! define min/max values of xaxis was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help.

The morganfree answer will work better because I don't know how many points I will have during a day. I just have to define **min** and **max** values of xAxis, the type have to be a datetime in my case. Then I am giving [timestamp,value] in series data. Ex:

```
xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     tickPixelInterval: 60, //spacing xaxis labels
     min: startTime, //Today, 00h in TS
     max: endTime //Today, 23h59 in TS
},

series: [
     { name:"test", 
       data:[[1482911520000,10],
             [1482911620000,11],
             [1482911720000,12],
             [1482911820000,13],
             [1482911920000,14]]
     }]
```

Thanks again, happy new year.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot with null values,

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 106.4, 129.2, 102,null],
    }]

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/pmws4dwz/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It need to know how many point I will have into my Graph but it is a pretty good solution !